# How to track Finger tip in OpenCV or OpenFrameworks?

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks

I want to develop a program which uses the webcam to track finger tips. When tracked, the finger tip will be like an index and I will be able to get its positions even if it is moved around. If anyone has any advice for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use some color papers wrapped around your finger tips to facilitate recognition.

Answer (score 2):

Setup is everything. First make sure you make it easy for yourself: have the proper lighting conditions ( either an IR LED + IR filter on camera or just high contrast between your surface and the fingers )

I imagine you would do blob tracking. I can't give you a solution for making sure the id of the detected blobs will always be the same, even if they go in out of the tracked area, but I would suggesting giving [Community Core Vision](http://ccv.nuigroup.com/)(used to be tbeta) a try and use the forums there as well.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

If you look around the internet, you'll find lots of DIY tutorials to make a touch table.

If you want to keep your fingers in the air, you could put some colour markers. This article might help: http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use color based tracking method or skin segmentation. in [CCV](http://ccv.nuigroup.com) latest version it supports finger tip detection.

try this as well :http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~smalik/downloads/2503_project_report.pdf